# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'products' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I have tried viewing the other solutions of the community, but nothing came in help.

I was just trying to match the inputs to database entries and thus show a result in the "products.html" page.

Would be grateful if anyone could breakdown the solution.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ProductForm
from .models import Product

    def home(request):
        form = ProductForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ProductForm(request.POST)
            form.save()
            if form.is_valid():
                return redirect('/')
        context = {
            'form':form 
        }
        return render(request, 'bye/home.html', context)
    def products(request, pk):
        product = Product.objects.get(id = pk)
        if request.method == "POST":
            return redirect('/')
    
        context = {
            'product': product
        }
        return render(request, 'bye/products.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .  import views

    urlpatterns = [
        
        path('', views.home, name ='home'),
        path('products/<str:pk>/', views.products, name = 'products')
    ]
```

**home.html**

```
</div>
    <div class = "col-md-12"><a href = "{% url 'products' product.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</a></div>
</div>
```

**products.html**

```
{% extends 'bye/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p></p>
{{product.name}}
{% endblock %}
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\okay\bye\views.py", line 17, in home
    return render(request, 'bye/home.html', context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\DJPROJ\try\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'products' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$']
[19/Jul/2021 23:10:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 155526
```

I cannot figure out where is the bug and why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#views.py
def products(request, **kwargs):
    pk = kwargs.get("pk")
    product = Product.objects.filter(id = pk)
    if product.exists():
        return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'product': product
    }
    return render(request, 'bye/products.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message with following code you got `<a href = "{% url 'products' '' %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</a>`. I means the value of `product.id` was empty.

**Option 1**

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,re_path
re_path(r'^products/(?P<pk>.*)/$', products, name='products'),
```

You can use any one of template url as follows,

1. `<a href = "{% url 'products','' %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</a>`
2. `<a href = "{% url 'products' 1 %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</a>  #replace 1 with product.id`

**Option 2**

urls.py

```
path('products/<str:pk>/', products,name='products'),
path('products/', products, name='products'),
```

You can use any one of template url as follows,

1. `<a href = "{% url 'products' %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</a>`
2. `<a href = "{% url 'products' 1 %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit</a>  #replace 1 with product.id`

Views.py

```
def products(request, pk=None):
    #Do the remaining code here
```